# Dataset for US Boat Launches (both Fresh and Salt)?

Tags: data-request, usa

Does anyone know where to find a dataset for US Boat Launches (both Fresh and Salt)? I have found several statewide results, but nothing on a national level. Does anyone know if this information is aggregated in a single location anywhere either as an open or paid dataset?

Comment: As you mentioned, I too have found several such datasets on a state level, but not seen one national. I believe you can find them for Oregon, Washington, Louisiana, and New York

Comment: Hi @Andrew... do you know of any other Boat Ramp/Boat Launch data sets or databases anywhere else that may be accessible nationwide either open or for purchase? Would really appreciate any guidance on this... Thanks!

Comment: I haven't looked to much into this area. But I did do a couple of Google queries (e.g., boat launch ramp datasets). I found that Rhode Island has a dataset to: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/public-access-points-recreational-boat-launching-ramp-and-marine-pump-out-facilities-for-fresh-428c8 . If you do the same query, you'll find there appears to be datasets for Maine and Texas as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov) has only regional boat launches, so if you need something larger (but less complete), check out OpenStreetMaps data. In particular, the tag [leisure=slipway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:leisure=slipway).

You can use the Overpass Turbo visual API to check out coverage of the tag, for example, this [query](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/E5d) (click "Run").

[image]

Check out this [answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511) for downloading bulk OSM files, filtering for your specific tags, and converting to various GIS formats.

---

Also note the [wikidata code](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q361945), for which you can do [Sparql queries](https://query.wikidata.org/).