# Seeking globally available road data for medium-scaled maps (1:200.000)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, africa

I am seeking open data of roads for medium scaled maps (1:200.000, 1:500.000 up to 1:1.000.000). For the whole world, at least Indonesia and Africa.

I know I could use OSM streets and somehow generalize them. But for my purposes this would be too time-consuming.

Comment: I don't think you'll find any open data superior to OSM.  When road data are open, chances are OSM have already included it.

Comment: I mean that I am looking for more generalized data than the OSM data. OSM road data is good for large-scaled maps. If I use that data, I have to spend a lot of time to generalize it.

Comment: I added OSM as an answer, but can you explain what you mean "generalize"?

Answer (score 3):

Despite your reluctance to use OSM data, check out [`osmfilter`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter), and in particular [`objectfilter`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter), which is exactly designed for this purpose.

```
./osmfilter africa.osm --keep="highway=primary =secondary" >streets.osm
```

The only real challenge is having enough space for the unzipped [planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) file (or individual continents or countries) and then running osmconvert/osmfilter on that big file. Otherwise, all the tools are ready to go.

Full data exports for [Africa](https://download.geofabrik.de/africa.html) and [Indonesia](https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/indonesia.html) are available from https://download.geofabrik.de

To convert from osm/pbf formats, which are specific to OSM, to GeoJSON, Shapefiles, *etc* - check out [`ogr2ogr`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

**update** since posting, I've switched from ogr2ogr to the node.js package [osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson) and for simple conversions I'm finding it much easier (and fast).

Comment: osmosis can also get the job done https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis

Comment: If you want to test what's available in OSM and how the tag system works I would recommend https://overpass-turbo.eu/