# Seeking Database of German and Austrian roads?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, database

Is there any way to get `region -> city -> road` database for some specific country. In this case I need For **Germany** and **Austria**. Databases I'm working with is `PostgreSQL` with `PostGIS` extension.

Where can I get this?

1. **Data:** Names of counties(regions), cities and roads. (Coordinates are bonus). Possible structure: county has many cities and roads. Road can belong to county and city or only county.
2. **Context:** Georeferencing static retroreflection testing of road signs;
3. **Region:** Germany and Austria;
4. **License:** Possible [open](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/whats-your-interpretation-of-the-open-in-open-data) dat;
5. **Format:** Simple tables, CSV or other of requested data;
6. **Authority:** It's important to be checked data;
7. **Non-answers:** Was seeking for something like [this](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). But lack of data.

Comment: This question is vastly more suited to GIS.SE where it started. There is already a global database of open road data called Open Street Map, and most of the people who will be able to answer questions about it reside on that  site.

Comment: see this answer https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511, using the DACH file from OSM (geofabrik download) http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/dach.html

Comment: Thanks, `Geofabrik` was the thing I was looking for.

Comment: marked as closed, based on the answer in the comments