# US Fire Hydrant locations data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa

I am looking for the location of fire hydrants all over the US.
I'm particulalrly interested in Rhode Island, Massachusetts, Maine, New Hampshire.

Comment: openstreetmap.org may or may not have this information

Answer (score 3):

OSM (Open Street Map) has the tag **[fire_hydrant](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:emergency=fire_hydrant)**. You can use the [overpass-turbo visual API](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) to check coverage. Here's a [sample query](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/C08) that will search for fire hydrants within the range of the viewable map to the right.

```
node
  [emergency=fire_hydrant]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

You should use this tool to work on your search parameters.

[image]

Overpass-turbo API does have an export data feature, but I think you'll have too much data to use the browser tool. Therefore, once you figure out what you are searching for, you'll want to download bulk regions (start small to test your code).

- Download the `latest` osm file from geofabrik:

  - Start small https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/rhode-island.html
  - Scale up https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html
- Convert the osm/pbf file to something, if needed, with osmconvert.
- Use [`osmfilter`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) or [`osmosis`](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis) to filter the bulk file for only the tags that you want, which can be based on your testing with the overpass-turbo API.
- Use one of many tools (e.g. [`ogr2ogr`](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)) to convert the osm file format to geojson, SQLite, CSV, Shapefiles, etc.

Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511

Answer (score 2):

For Rhode Island, there are fire hydrants on RIGIS;

http://www.rigis.org/datasets/e-911-fire-hydrants