# Finding POI across India

Tags: india, travel

I'm looking for data containing point of interests or POI across India.
Only place name, location and state will be enough. I don't need details like it's location or it's shape.

Details like this will be good
**Victoria Memorial - Museum - West Bengal**
Data like this can be found from Google search but I'm looking for something like a database containing such infos.

Where can I get something like this for offline use ?

Comment: please look through the OSM answers, where you can download bulk data (e.g all of India) and then extract specific tags: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13333/1511

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Google Places](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places) API? You can get place information that you see on Google Maps through [searching](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). There is a free $200 quota per month, that may provide you enough?