# Location (lat, long) of cell towers across the USA

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa

Does anyone know of any complete database of cell tower locations with the following information?

```
Lat, long of cell tower
MCC, MNC, LAC, Cell ID
Range
Signal strength
```

I have checked out the data from Open Cell ID, RadioCell, and Mylnikov and they seem to be incomplete. Some lat-long is randomly placed on an empty open field.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Open Data SE. Can you be a bit more clear and specify a region that you're interested in?

Comment: I am looking to map all cell towers across the US in all the states.

Comment: Many cell towers actually are in the middle of otherwise empty fields. Perhaps you're looking at old imagery, from before the cell towers were built.

Answer (score 2):

it's not the US, but maybe interesting for others:

Switzerland (official) cellular data/maps

GSM: https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bakom.mobil-antennenstandorte-gsm/

LTE: https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bakom.mobil-antennenstandorte-lte/

UMTS: https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bakom.mobil-antennenstandorte-umts/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try search in [gsm coverage maps](http://maps.mobileworldlive.com/network.php?cid=169&cname=United%20States), some ones has maps, but you can try fetch kml data

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get tower locations from OSM

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:communication:mobile_phone

See [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511) about downloading bulk files (entire US) and then filtering for specific tags (for example, communication=mobile_phone)

[image]

https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/?key=communication%3Amobile_phone#map

Answer (score 0):

Open Cell iD

https://opencellid.org/

> OpenCelliD is working towards creating an open cellular dataset that is driven and inspired by the community. This cellular data is used for a multitude of commercial/private purposes by patrons worldwide. From locating devices to understanding network coverage patterns; OpenCelliD enables it by providing convenient access to the data via an API and data dumps.

https://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_use_the_OpenCellID_API_free_of_charge.3F

As seen here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26169747