# Canada, USA - fuel stations, grocery stores

Tags: geospatial, usa, canada, north-america

I am looking for free data where fuel stations and grocery stores are located in Canada and the USA, that can be exported/downloaded in any format (csv, shp, json, txt, kml, ...).

Do you know of any databases, services, open data? I already had a look at Open Data Canada, which does not provide anything regarding these layers.

Comment: it's going to be OSM, with several tags (see, for example, https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:shop=supermarket). You can search this forum for OSM export, similar to this question https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511

Comment: Note that OSM data is crowd-sourced data with many different contributors, so the tags are not used consistently. You may want to cast a wide net at first, then chop down the data once you have it. Use their wiki to figure out which tags could possibly be relevant, download all the points with those tags in your AOI, and finally remove any extra points.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the US from a government source. I thought the departments of transportation for each US state might have data at least for highway rest stops, but if they do it's not easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

If you are by any chances affiliated to a Canadian university you get free access to DMTI POI data that includes all that information for Canada. All of this is located in the Scholar GeoPortal repository at http://geo2.scholarsportal.info/

For the US there is a similar company called SimplyAnalytics that also has free access through many Canadian universities.