# Where can i get an API of all oil & gas wells in America?

Tags: data-request, usa, api

I am looking for an API for oil and gas wells, including their name and location. I know each state has has this data for download but is there an API out there?

I know of some but they are at least $3,000+. Is there any that are reasonably price ones?

Answer (score 1):

OpenStreetMap has the data, specifically 70k+ entries with the tag "[man_made=petroleum_well](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Dpetroleum_well)" (also the less used "[man_made=pumping_rig](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:man_made%3Dpumping_rig)". Here's how [they look on the map](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/?key=man_made&value=petroleum_well#map):

[image]

There are many tools to export all the data for a set of tags. In particular, start with manual searches using the [OverPass-Turbo API](https://overpass-turbo.eu/), to see if this tag has good coverage for places you know of. Then start to read about bulk exports with [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12430/1511).

Once you download the bulk.osm file, you'd run something like this

```
./osmfilter bulk.osm --keep="man_made=pumping_rig =petroleum_well" > oil_wells.osm
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 3k.  Texas alone will cost you $4500 for the RAW COBOL tables.  Several sites host the data such as drilling info or others but most are incomplete and don't allow downloads as this is highly valuable information.